# My DOM doesn't update, but my dataModel does

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My DOM doesn't update when I Call the 'Click' function.
It does update the datamodel. When I put an alert(); in the Click function then I can see the correct values.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind='foreach: Areas'>
    <table>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: Categories">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div data-bind='click: Click'>
              <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            </div>
            <div data-bind='visible: visible'>
              <div data-bind="foreach: products">
                <div data-bind="text: text1"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Click = function (categorie) {
    //alert(toggleContentBool(Categorie.visible));
    Categorie.visible = toggleContentBool(Categorie.visible);
}

function toggleContentBool(switcher) {
    if (switcher) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function TouchArea(jsonObject) {
    var self = this;
    self.productCategories = ko.observableArray(jsonObject.Categories);
}

function Product(text1, text2, text3, text4) {
    var self = this;
    self.text1 = text1;
};

function Categorie(name ) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.visible = ko.observable(true);
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
}

function dataLoader() {
    this.jsonTouchArea = '{"Categories":[{"name":"11111","visible":true,"products":[{"text1":"text"},{"text1":"text"}]},{"name":"22222","visible":true,"products":[{"text1":"text"},{"text1":"text"}]}]}';
    return JSON.parse(this.jsonTouchArea);
}
```

Also important: the Categories array gets loaded with a json object. and I suspect it will have to do something with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *replace* your observable, change its state:

```
Categorie.visible(toggleContentBool(Categorie.visible()));
```

Your code was replacing the observable with a boolean (and was always switching it to `false`, because you were passing a function reference into your `toggleContentBool`, and function references are truthy).

Remember that observables are *functions*.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed why it didn't work. Turn's out the json load changes all the observables to flat variables.